# Visual or open source library for bulk upload to oracleOpen source library for bulk upload to oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

good afternoon friends,

I am working with excel files (xlsx) to load massive data to oracle, but I am having problems loading 160 MB excel files, (more than 1 million records and 40 columns).
Up to 100MB, 700K is loading me, it takes a bit but loading.

I am thinking of stopping using the bulkCopy library, and looking for another way to do it, can you tell me if there is any open source library that is better or more efficient for uploading files to oracle.

With the 160MB files (over 1 million records) I am getting a message of:

SYSTEM.OutOfMemoryException in mscorlib.dll

clearly indicates that I am missing memory.

1-Do all mass loading methods load the files into memory?

2-within the code that I share, is there a way that reads 50% of the content of the excel "select * from [file$]" process and then reads the other 50% so as not to have memory problems.

3-I can have ODP.NET 32 and 64 bit on the same computer without generating conflict.

I am using the oracle ODP.NET 32 bit library, since we cannot install the 64 bit library, so I am evaluating looking for an open source library that can do the job.

I will appreciate any comments and help.

Thanks,
Greetings.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim _connString As String = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.1.100.1)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = ORACLE))); User Id=USER; password=PASS;"
        Dim rutacarpeta As String
        Dim NombreArchivo As String
        Dim tablaBBDD As String
        'Dim ot As OracleTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
        Using conn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(_connString)
            conn.Open()
            Dim ot As OracleTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
            Try

                rutacarpeta = "C:\2021\"
                NombreArchivo = "FILE_0.xlsx"
                tablaBBDD = "FILE_TEST"
                Dim xlsxConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;';"
                xlsxConn = String.Format(xlsxConn, rutacarpeta + NombreArchivo).Trim()

                Using excel_con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(xlsxConn)
                    excel_con.Open()
                    'Dim hoja As String = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing).Rows(0)()
                    Dim command As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter ("SELECT * FROM [FILE$]", excel_con)

                    Dim dtset As new dataset
                    command.fill(dtset)
                     dim dr as datatable =dtset.tables(0)
                     row_file_excel=dr.rows.count

                    Using bulkCopy As OracleBulkCopy = New OracleBulkCopy(conn)
                        bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 90000
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tablaBBDD
                     

                   bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr)

                        ot.Commit()

                        bulkCopy.Close()
                    End Using
                End Using

            Catch ex As Exception
                Try
                    ot.Rollback()
                Catch ex1 As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message)
                End Try

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: You don't want to put that much data into a transaction.

Comment: Well, I would split this into two problems. You up-load the files first - to some folder. You THEN process the files. I would not attempt to mix up the up-loading process and the data process tasks as one and the same. So, up load files. Show the up-loaded files - maybe size etc., and then have a processing button and task to to the 2nd step.

Comment: hi thanks for the answers, i'm checking and i see that it crashes when: command.fill (dtset), it must be because of the large number of records, but i can't think of anything. About the processes at the end I will divide it into 2 as you say, but it is not the problem. Thank you,